# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, insert, identity-insert

I'm trying to insert records in a table that has got an identity column.  For various reasons, this should not be a straight insert, but it should have the same ID as the foreign table.
So I run:

```
EXECUTE ('SET IDENTITY_INSERT RemoteDB.dbo.FrameContent ON')

INSERT INTO [RemoteDB].[dbo].[FrameContent] ([ID],[FrameID],[PacketType]) 
SELECT [ID],[FrameID],[PacketType]
FROM FrameContent 
WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT [ID] FROM [RemoteDB].[dbo].[FrameContent])
```

And I get the error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'FrameContent' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Any ideas? It complains that IDENTITY_INSERT should not be OFF, but I am setting it to ON.

Comment: Why do you use `execute` to run the `SET` command?

Comment: Sorry - copy and paste issue.  I'm actually compiling a string with variables.  Should be SET for this example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to set `dentity_insert` outside `execute`:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT RemoteDB.dbo.FrameContent ON;
INSERT ...
```

If you set it inside `execute`, it will only apply to other statements inside the `execute`.

Comment: Yip, that will work.  Now I have to figure out how to pass the table name as a variable (that was the reason for using the Execute).  Thanks

Comment: Here you go.
`code`
declare @tables Table(id smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1), 
  name nvarchar(100))
insert @tables
 SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
 
declare @i int
declare @numrows int
declare @tableName nvarchar(100)
set @i = 1
set @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tables)
IF @numrows > 0 WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @tables)) BEGIN
 SET @tableName = (SELECT name FROM @tables WHERE id = @i)
 exec [dbo].[whateverproc] @tableName
 SET @i = @i + 1
END